# Get Amplitude or Frequency of Audio Played in Media Player in Android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, frequency

I am a beginner to Android.I want to find the frequency density or volume amplitude in Android or using Android Media Player for an mp3 file.I tried many different ways but I didn't got succeeded.Can you please help me with this

I have found this code but it is giving the getMaxAmplitude() value in audio recorder time but not getting the at the time of playing mp3 file.
Following is the link: [What does Android's getMaxAmplitude() function for the MediaRecorder actually give me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655703/what-does-androids-getmaxamplitude-function-for-the-mediarecorder-actually-gi)

```
public double getNoiseLevel() 
{
    Log.d("SPLService", "getNoiseLevel() ");
    int x = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
    double x2 = x;
    Log.d("SPLService", "x="+x);
    double db = (20 * Math.log10(x2 / REFERENCE));
    //Log.d("SPLService", "db="+db);
    if(db>0)
    {
        return db;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I also refer of ringdroid link :https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/

I also checked FFT but it is at the recording time.I need to detect the frequency / Amplitude while playing the Audio File (mp3 file).

Comment: Include what you've tried. It helps if you show what parts of the documentation you've checked, and if anything confused you.

Comment: For sound analisys, you'll need to use **FFT** (Fast Fourier Transformation).

Answer (score 0):

**`mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()` Returns the maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call, or 0 when called for the first time**

It is equivalent to do:

```
max(abs(signal));
```

You need check your `Reference` variable use 1.0 to floating point data representation or  32767 to short int!

To convert the maximum absolute amplitude to dB you need do `20 * log10(x/Reference)`

An equivalent code in matlab show the concept:

```
% create a audio signal in float point at 90dB
signal = 10^(90/20)*sin(2*pi*f/Fs*t)';
%equivalent of mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()
x = max(abs(signal));
%find dB (Reference for this example is 1.0 data in float point)
decibel = 20 * log10(x/1.0)
```

Result is `89.9955`

To show decibel while playing mp3 file you need call `getNoiseLevel()` to every processed frame!