# How can I make Android decibel measuring more accurate? Is it correct at all?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, measure

Soooo, I'm trying to write an Android app to measure sound level of environment.

I know that those kind of questions were asked many, many times and I've read many of them, but i'm still not sure, if my code is good.

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private TextView AmpCur, DbCur;

Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //change text to actual amplitude
        int Amp = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        double db = 20 * Math.log10((double)Amp / 32767.0);
        double db2 = 20 * Math.log10((double)Amp);
        int db2I = (int) Math.round(db2);
        Log.i("SoundMeasure", "amp=" + Amp + " db=" + db + " db2=" + db2);

        AmpCur.setText(Integer.toString(Amp));
        DbCur.setText(Integer.toString(db2I));
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 250);
    }
};

public void RecorderInit() {

    String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SoundMeasure", "prepare() fail");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 250);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound_measure);

    AmpCur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amp_cur);
    DbCur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.db_cur);
} 
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        RecorderInit();
    }
}
```

App works, but the values are... a bit weird.

In very silent room, where other apps show ~15dB, I have

amp ~80 db ~-50 db2 ~40

When in blow into mic, other apps show 110+dB, and mine shows

amp 32767 db 0 db2 90

I've read that maxAmplitude can't get over 32767 and phones mics can't measure more than 90dB, but how other apps do that?

Answer (score 1):

At least your reference value of 32767 seems wrong. You can deduce this from the db values you get. You use a value that is per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655703/what-does-androids-getmaxamplitude-function-for-the-mediarecorder-actually-gi) the maximum that a mobile phone microphone can record. Since you scale with this, in all but the maximum apmlitude cases you will get a negative value because of how logarithm works. `Log10` of (32767.0 / 32767.0) will be 0 because `log(1) = 0`. values smaller than one will approach negative infinity.

Your formula for `db2` would also be wrong because you essentially use a reference of 1. The last answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655703/what-does-androids-getmaxamplitude-function-for-the-mediarecorder-actually-gi) seems to have figured out a proper reference value but it also states that you should not use `getMaxAmplitude` alone. He also converts the value to pascals before using a reference of `0.00002`. This is probably how other apps go about calculating the decibels.

Answer (score 1):

Amplitudes in dB are always a relative measure against a reference point.

You are calculating dBFS which is power relative to the maximum sample value of the system

`dBFS = 20 * log10(V/V0)`

where: `V` is the measured signal voltage (in this case, sample value) and V0 is the reference point.

It seems that you are trying to build a Sound Pressure Level meter. These measure air pressure, and typically the [dBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting) scale is used.  This is weighted and filtered, having time and frequency response characteristics.  You are measuring peak amplitude, which will read higher.

There are number of practical considerations:

- You assume the microphone responds linearly to air-pressure variations
- AGC and the HPF needs to be disabled for the microphone
- The frequency response needs to be wide enough and flat.
- The basic theory of measurement dictates that you need a pair of calibration points to calculate the gain of the system and any DC bias.

In practice, these last two points make building a practical SPL meter app for Android very difficult - you need to calibrate the app for each type of device it runs on (potentially a huge number) - and compensate for frequency response of the system if it's not linear.  There is no particular requirement or commercial imperative for Android phone OEMs to normalise the signals from microphones.